# Color switching of an image using C++ code

Tags: c++, image-processing

Since i am quiet new to C++ and Image processing i have a problem modifying and adding a function to the code.
The requirement is only to switch between the RGB colors.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "ctype.h"
#include "math.h"

class myImageData
{
private:
    int mW;
    int mH;
    int mCH;
    double * mData;

    void SkipComments(FILE *fp)
    {
        int ch;
        char line[100];

        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isspace(ch))
            ;

        if (ch == '#')
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
            SkipComments(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

public:

    myImageData(void)
    {
        this->mData = NULL;
    }

    ~myImageData()
    {
        if (this->mData != NULL)
        {
            delete[] this->mData;
        }
    }

    void init(int W, int H, int CH)
    {
        this->mW = W;
        this->mH = H;
        this->mCH = CH;

        if (this->mData != NULL)
            delete[] this->mData;

        this->mData = new double[(this->mW)*(this->mH)*(this->mCH)];
    }

    int getWidth(void)
    {
        return this->mW;
    }

    int getHeight(void)
    {
        return this->mH;
    }

    int getCH(void)
    {
        return this->mCH;
    }

    double * getDataPtr(void)
    {
        return this->mData;
    }

    double get(int x, int y)
    {
        return this->mData[y*(this->mW) + x];
    }

    double get(int x, int y, int CH)
    {
        return this->mData[this->mCH * (y*(this->mW) + x) + CH];
    }

    void set(int x, int y, double value)
    {
        this->mData[y*(this->mW) + x] = value;
    }

    void set(int x, int y, int CH, double value)
    {
        this->mData[this->mCH *(y*(this->mW) + x) + CH] = value;
    }

    void read(const char *filename);
    void save(const char *filename);
};


void myImageData::read(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1); //abnormal termination
    }
    printf("Read an image from: %s\n", filename);

    // read ppm/pgm header

    char buf[256];
    char filetype[256];
    int W, H, Range, CH;

    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
    sscanf(buf, "%s", filetype);

    SkipComments(file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
    sscanf(buf, "%d%d", &W, &H);

    SkipComments(file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &Range);
    //printf("Header: %s, %d, %d, %d\n", filetype, W, H, Range);

    SkipComments(file);

    if (strcmp(filetype, "P5") == 0)
    {
        CH = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(filetype, "P6") == 0)
    {
        CH = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown image type\n");
        exit(1); //abnormal termination
    }

    if (Range != 255){
        printf("Invalid data\n");
        exit(1); //abnormal termination
    }

    // create myImageData class

    init(W, H, CH);

    // read ppm data

    int datalength = this->mW * this->mH * this->mCH;
    unsigned char * temp = new unsigned char[datalength];
    fread(temp, sizeof(unsigned char), datalength, file);

    double * ptr1 = this->mData;
    unsigned char *ptr2 = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++){
        *ptr1 = (double)*ptr2;
        ptr1++;
        ptr2++;
    }

    delete[] temp;

    fclose(file);

}

void myImageData::save(const char *filename){

    char filenamefull[256];
    if (this->mCH == 1){
        sprintf(filenamefull, "%s.pgm", filename);
    }
    else{
        sprintf(filenamefull, "%s.ppm", filename);
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(filenamefull, "w");
    printf("Write an image to: %s \n", filenamefull);

    if (this->mCH == 1){
        fprintf(file, "P5\n");
    }
    else{
        fprintf(file, "P6\n");
    }

    fprintf(file, "%d %d\n", this->mW, this->mH);
    fprintf(file, "255\n");

    int datalength = this->mW * this->mH * this->mCH;
    unsigned char * temp = new unsigned char[datalength];

    double * ptr1 = this->mData;
    unsigned char * ptr2 = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++){
        double value = *ptr1;
        value = round(value);
        if (value > 255) value = 255;
        if (value < 0) value = 0;
        *ptr2 = (unsigned char)value;
        ptr1++;
        ptr2++;
    }

    fwrite(temp, sizeof(unsigned char), datalength, file);
    delete[] temp;

    fprintf(file, "Â¥n");

    fclose(file);
}
```

The errors i am having:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: We need some context here.  Show us the function to be modified.

Comment: This is a nice simple problem that could have already been answered if you've provided code! It would help also to mention the compiler and libraries you might be using, too.

Comment: Sorry i am adding the code right now

Comment: Which function is causing you problems? What exactly does it need to do? (switch between colours is too vague! output just one channel? swap channels?) What have you tried?

Comment: @user3543384 _' i am adding the code right now'_ That was a quite bad idea for clarifiying anything ....

Comment: The project is to import a picture, switch the RGB and export it to a new file.
We were given the previous code.

Comment: Please tell us what "Switch the RGB" means! It is not an obvious phrase! _You have to give us this information in order to get useful answers!_

Comment: What lines (please highlight) are having issues with?  (Have you used a debugger?)

Comment: The errors i am having:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: It sounds like you don't even have a complete application.

Comment: Please verify that your Visual Studio setup parameters are correct, especially console vs. window and multi-char vs. unicode vs. none.

Comment: Sorry switching between RGB (Red Green Blue) within the program

Comment: Do you have a `main` function? Or a `tmain`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is what i am asking for ... i cant find it to modify it

Comment: Can these answers help: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&hs=bht&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=stackoverflow+unresolved+symbol+visual+studio+main&oq=stackoverflow+unresolved+symbol+visual+studio+main&gs_l=serp.3...4352.5088.0.5927.5.5.0.0.0.0.140.498.3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.43.serp..5.0.0.QpNYBmkbD8o

Comment: I suggest you open your favorite search engine and type "lnk1120 ___tmainCRTStartup error".

Comment: What does "switching between RGB" mean? Please don't just tell me it means "switching between RGB" again. You've done that several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have no `main` function. No surprise that your code doesn't work.. all you have is a class to load, save and manipulate PPM image files.

You appear to me using Visual Studio, so you'll need a function that looks like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    myImageData image;
    image.read("atestfile.ppm");

    // do some stuff to your image

    image.write("outputfile.ppm");
}
```

I'm assuming you have a test image in PPM format you can use here, of course.

Now this is madness:

```
double * ptr1 = this->mData;
unsigned char * ptr2 = temp;

for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++){
    double value = *ptr1;
    value = round(value);
    if (value > 255) value = 255;
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    *ptr2 = (unsigned char)value;
    ptr1++;
    ptr2++;
}
```

You've read from an `unsigned char`, so there's no point stuffing it into a `double`, and there's *definitely* no point in checking if the value lies outside of 0 to 255. Why are you storing things in doubles? It makes no sense! Even if you did do something that needed a full double-precision floating point value per channel, you throw it all away in the output when you clamp everything to 0-255 again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++){
    double value = *ptr1;
    value = round(value);
    if (value > 255) value = 255;
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    *ptr2 = (unsigned char)value;
    ptr1++;
    ptr2++;
}
```

Also, this is basically C dressed up in a thin C++ veneer. That's okay, everyone has to start somewhere. But instead of using `new` to create an array, you can do this:

```
// read ppm data

int datalength = this->mW * this->mH * this->mCH;

// using a std::vector here means that the allocated memory will be freed
// automatically, even in the result of an error occurring.
std::vector<unsigned char> temp(datalength);
fread(&temp[0], sizeof(unsigned char), datalength, file);
```

I'd also consider using `iostream` classes such as `fstream` instead of `fread` and `fopen` and so on. But this is not really the place to get into those kinds of details.

Anyway, What to do with your image once it is loaded? You've got dead easy helper functions to read and write pixel values, which will let you do pretty much anything you want. Here's a simple example, swapping the R and B channels. You might get something better when you actually tell us what you wanted.

```
void swapRB(myImageData& image)
{
    assert(image.getCH() == 3);

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth())
    {
        for (int y = 0; x < image.getHeight())
        {
            double R = image.get(x, y, 0);
            double G = image.get(x, y, 1);
            double B = image.get(x, y, 2);

            image.set(x, y, 0, B);
            image.set(x, y, 2, R);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... I am still new in this field and i appreciate your help a lot.